# How can I synchronize data between XML Files and SQLite?

Tags: java, xml, database, sqlite

I have a XML File which I read data from XML File into Java Object and then insert these Java Objects into SQLite Database.
Then I modify my XML File and insert more data into it, how can I keep data between XML File and SQLite synchronized.
My XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Employees xmlns="https://www.journaldev.com/employee">
    <Employee id="1">
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
        <gender>Male</gender>
    </Employee>

    <Employee id="2">
        <name>Lisa</name>
        <age>35</age>
        <role>Manager</role>
        <gender>Female</gender>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Code to read XML File Employee in Java
https://anotepad.com/notes/qnn7nb2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a file watcher and since jdk1.7, you have the possibility to do this via [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

A working example can be found in the [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview)